# sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, sqlsrv

I've searched high and low for this and I can't wrap my head around it.  I have a form to search Permit Applications. Input your permit number and it runs 3 queries against 3 separate SQL Server views.  The queries are almost identical in the same if statement but the last one fails.  I've performed a `var_dump($query_insp_history)` copied the output and run a new query directly in SSMS and it works just fine.  Is there some other error checking that will give me more detail other than `sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`?  I believe I have my parameters setup correctly, please let me know if it should be structured differently.

The `// Application Inspection History Section` is the part giving me issues.  I just can't figure it out as it *appears* it's setup the same way the other two queries are.  I receive the error at this line of code `while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_insp_history, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){`

`var_dump($sql_insp_history);` 
returns
 `bool(false)`
`var_dump($query_insp_history);` 
returns
`string(81) "SELECT * FROM my.dbo.vw_Permit_App_Insp_History WHERE (LTRIM(APNO) = '123456')"`
Again, copying this into SSMS runs correctly...

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container content">

<form method="POST" name="permit_search" action="">
    <input type="number" id="apno" name="apno" class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="submit" name="apnosearch" id="apnosearch" value="Submit" class="col-sm-4">
</form>
<br/>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$serverName = "my_server";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"myDb", "UID"=>"myUser", "PWD"=>"myPass", "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn === false) {
    echo "Could not connect.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Query variables

$searchapno = $_POST['apno'];

$where_permit_info = "WHERE (LTRIM(APNO) = '$searchapno')";
$where_review_history = "WHERE (LTRIM(APNO) = '$searchapno') ORDER BY ACTTYPE, TYPENO ASC";
$where_insp_history = "WHERE (LTRIM(APNO) = '$searchapno') ORDER BY INSPTYPE, TYPENO ASC";

$query_permit_info = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM my.dbo.vw_Permit_Information $where_permit_info";
$query_review_history = "SELECT * FROM my.dbo.vw_Permit_Plan_Review_History $where_review_history";
$query_insp_history = "SELECT * FROM my.dbo.vw_Permit_App_Insp_History $where_insp_history";

// Overall Permit Information

if (isset($_POST['apno'])) {
    $sql_permit_info = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_permit_info);
    while ($row= sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_permit_info, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<strong>Name:</strong>  ".$row['APNAME']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Number:</strong>  ".$row['APNO']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Address:</strong>  ".$row['STNO']." ".$row['PREDIR']." ".$row['STNAME']." ".$row['SUFFIX']." ".$row['POSTDIR']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Description:</strong>  ".$row['DESCRIPT']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Status:</strong>  ".$row['STAT']."<br>";
        echo "<h3>Application Stages</h3><br>";
        echo "<strong>Date Processed:</strong>  ".$row['ADDDTTM']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Date Issued:</strong>  ".$row['ISSDTTM']."<br>";
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $sql_permit_info);

    // Plan Review History Section

    echo "<h3>Plan Review History</h3>";
    echo "<div class='nimbus_table_minimal'>";
    echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Added</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Status Date</th>
                    <th>Dept</th>
                </tr>";
    $sql_review_history = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_review_history);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_review_history, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['DESCRIPT']." ".$row['TYPENO']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ADDDTTM']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['STAT']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['STATDTTM']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['DEPT']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $sql_review_history);
    echo "</tbody></table></div>";

    // Application Inspection History Section

    echo "<h3>Application Inspection History</h3>";
    echo "<div class='nimbus_table_minimal'>";
    echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Number and Inspection</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Inspector</th>
                </tr>";
    $sql_insp_history = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_insp_history);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_insp_history, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['DESCRIPT']." ".$row['TYPENO']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['STAT']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['EMPLAST']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $sql_insp_history);
    echo "</tbody></table></div>";

}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is about Microsoft SQL server, not MySQL.  I doubt it's about WordPress.

Comment: @O.Jones Apologies for selecting the wrong tag.  I added the WordPress tag as the site is built on WordPress so I wasn't sure if there was anything additional I needed to accommodate...

Answer (score 1):

[According to its documentation, sqlsrv_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) returns `false` if it gets an error or a statement resource on success.

You must get in the habit of checking errors in SQL operations, or you'll never know whose woods you stop near, Mr. Frost.

You want something like this:

```
$sql_permit_info = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_permit_info);  
if ($sql_permit_info === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} 
while ($row= sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_permit_info, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: Thank you.  I still get the same error at the same location.  At the beginning of the file I placed `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`I do like the inline way of checking.  Is there anything else I can add to expand upon the error message?  Currently I'm taking apart the view and running everything one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be incorrect with the View I was using.  I pulled the raw SELECT statement out of the view and inserted into my `$sql_permint_info` and all is working fine now.